# оптимизация google adsense

Tags: оптимизация

здравствуйте, я заметил что после установки рекламы от google, сайт стал немного тормозить при скроллинге если эта реклама есть в зоне видимости, а так же выросла нагрузка от сайта в диспетчере задач браузера, можно ли это как то "пофиксить" не убирая саму рекламу?